# Delete row table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a table like this

```
id  name    address     action
--------------------------------------
s1  n1  a1      delete
s2  n2  a2      delete
```

Delete is a link for example `<a href="http://localhost/student/delete/1">`. In the real case I delete the student using ajax. In order to simplify the code, I just alert the link and omit the ajax script. I just wanna know How to delete row from the html document using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function(event) {
    alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(href);
        event.preventDefault();
   });
);
```

I want, After I alert the link the selected row will be remove automatically. Is there any suggestion how to implement this one ?

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup?

Comment: Do you want to remove the row from the Database table, or the HTML table? Or both?

Comment: @Douwe Would you know how to have this delete the html and database table? I just came across this question when searching for an answer for the same sort of problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to call preventDefault(). Simply returning false from the event handler has the same effect.

To remove the row where the `<a>` link is located, you can call $(this).closest("tr").remove():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function(event) {
    alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(href);
    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // remove row
    return false; // prevents default behavior
   });
);
```

Comment: nice... i didn't know about `closest`

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to each `<tr>` called `row_9714` and add an id `9714` to the link. Then in your click event handler call:

```
var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
$("#row_" + thisId).remove();
```

Note -- 9714 is just a dummy ID. Just use a unique number here for each row.

Comment: according to you, which one is the best practice.

I use dummy id like $("#row_" + thisId).remove();
 or I use closest selector like $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // remove row

Comment: While this will work, I think this solution is a little overkill. It can be done a lot cleaner

Comment: why you said that the psychotik answer is overkill ?

Comment: Getting the id first, and then building a string to select the row with a specific id is not very efficient. After all, jQuery offers very nice ways of selecting the parent container(s) of any element

Answer (score 0):

This example removes rows from a table with JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#my_table .remove_row").click(function () {
 $(this).parents("tr:first")[0].remove();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table"  border="1" id="my_table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><button type="button" class="remove_row">X</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><button type="button" class="remove_row">X</button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```